# Proving a limit of the following rational function

Tags: calculus, limits

DISCLAIMER: I just need help with rough work rather than a proof ($\epsilon - \delta$). Proof becomes easy when you find a delta. So im trying to get bounds for the extra term so i can find the delta.

Im supposed to find $$\lim_{x \rightarrow -2} \frac{x^2 - 4}{x^3 + 8} = -\frac{1}{3}$$
So far i expanded it and got the following $$|\frac{3(x - 2)(x + 2) + (x + 2)(x^2 - 2x + 4)}{3(x + 2)(x^2 - 2x + 4)}|$$
Would it okay if i could cancel the $(x+2)$ term from the function. My only concern is that it is the only quantity we have complete control over since we control delta. I dont see a further simplification. The closest I came was to split the function and further simplify it which is $$\frac{(x-2)}{(x^2 - 2x + 4)} +\frac{1}{3}$$
Any insight is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why not just use L'Hopital's Rule?

Comment: @SaketGurjar im required to use epsilon delta proofs only

Comment: $\frac{x-2}{x^2-2x+4}=\frac1{x+\frac4{x-2}}$  may help.

Comment: @saulspatz im having a hard time giving bounds to that function

Comment: You should continue with the expression you got at the end and try to bound it by a simpler function. But before this you should actually add those two fractions to get a single fraction.

Answer (score 0):

You can factor out $x+2$ from both numerator and denominator and cancel it. That is the easiest way, since both are [equivalent infinitesimals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#Equivalent_infinitesimal)

$$L = \lim_{x \to -2}\frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{(x+2)(x^2-2x+4)} = \lim_{x \to -2} \frac{x-2}{x^2-2x+4} = -\frac 13$$

Comment: yeah thats what i end up with my calculation above.

Comment: But this doesn't give the OP the $\epsilon-\delta$ proof he asks for.